# In MySQL how do I edit multiple records with the same value at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql

I hope I've formatted this questions correctly, using 1&1 phpMyAdmin I need to update multiple records with the same value and want to see if there's an automated way of doing this rather than going through each record individually.

For example, I have about 200 rows to edit where league_id = 17 which currently have a value of 0 in the columns division_id and season_id and I want to make the division_id for each row 16 and the season_id for each row 10.

I can obviously go through each record and update it manually but that's going to be quite time consuming and I want to see if there is a way to update all 200 rows at the same time?

I hope this makes sense but forgive me if it's not formatted correctly and let me know if there's any other information needed to answer this.

Many Thanks

Comment: we need some code... to correct it and help you

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an idea of what code you need, this isn't something I've got a lot of knowledge of.

Comment: just run sql update query without giving where condition   UPDATE `tablename` SET `division_id`=[value-1], `season_id`=[value-2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update using one query, match the condition and execute update command like this:

```
update table_name set division_id = 16, season_id = 10 
where division_id = 0 and season_id = 0;
```

Comment: thanks, I just tried that but got this error: SQL query:


update `hit_fixture` set `division_id` =16, `season_id` =10 where `league_id` =17 `division_id` =0 and `season_id`  =0 
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`division_id` =0 and `season_id`  =0' at line 1

Comment: ignore that, just realised I forgot to add an 'and' after the league_id, that's worked perfectly!